# load base class for tests from conftest in pytest

Tags: pytest, testinfra

We have a lot of repeated tests for many applications (testinfra). I want to create BaseClass to be inherited by app-specific test classes to reduce boilerplate of repeated tests (is this service running? is this port listen?).

We have tests in a structure like this `/tests/{app-name}/test_{app_name}.py`. There is `/tests/conftest.py` file with pytest fixtures.

I'm trying to find a way to put `BaseClass` somewhere in `conftest.py` or near it and to be able import it.

The problems:

- tests are run in CI and I don't want to install any modules/packages (that means I can't just `pip install` module with BaseClass and than `from thismodule import BaseClass`)
- Due to convention we must use dashes in `{app-name}`. That beaks all relative imports as `app-name` is not a package for python, even there if `__init__.py` is present.

Is any reasonable way to load class from a specific file, or get it for free (magic at collection time) from pytest?

Comment: You can put the class in any module that is in `sys.path` when tests are executed. E.g. create a `tests/utils.py` and use `from utils import BaseClass` in test modules. You may get issues with your IDE though, but that's a different story.

Comment: Or have a `main_app/testing.py` which collects all test-specific stuff and is excluded from the distribution files.

Comment: Yes, I've opted for   `from utils import BaseClass`. I'm not sure why this import worked, though, as 'tests' is not in sys.path for normal python. Is it so for pytest-run tests?

Comment: `tests` is added to `sys.path` by pytest since you have a `tests/conftest.py` module and pytest has to install the local plugin in the conftest.